# How to place v-chips inside a textarea or editable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Currently I am using Vue.js to build the front end of a webapp, and I have code as follows:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="renders" v-html="text"></div>
```

Where "text" is:

```
"<v-chip id=\"keyword\"> " + somewords + "</v-chip>"
```

But this does not render text as v-chips, although the css from #keyword id is still applied. How can I also apply the v-chip css to such a process?

Comment: **v-html**: _"Updates the element’s innerHTML. Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates."_ ([source](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html))

Comment: As Sovalina said, only plain standard html will be inserted and a v-chip is not an html element. Can you not just insert the 'somewords' as v-html="somewords" in a v-chip tag? Like `<v-chip id="keywords" v-html="somewords"></v-chip>`